# Capture block in object initializer in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class `Notification::Pseudo` in my rails application that has a custom `initialize` method. I would like this method to capture the output of the block that was passed to `new` and use that as the value for `@message`

```
class Notification::Pseudo
  attr_accessor :message
  def initialize(&block)
    @message = begin
      capture(&block) if block_given?
    end || ""
  end
end
```

In my view I then have something like

```
- notification = Notification::Pseudo.new do
  This is a test!
```

This doesn't work though. This gives me the error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`.

What is wrong w/ my initializer?

Comment: Where is the `capture` method coming from? The error lies there I think.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture

Comment: This is a method available in views and templates but you're using it on a class. What exactly do you want your `@message` to be in the case of your example?

Comment: @message should become what ever is yielded from the block (in my example it would be "This is a test!").

Comment: Show us exactly your view. "This is a test" is a string?

Comment: @Agis Yes, "This is a Test!" is a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`capture` method you are calling is defined on Kernel module. You want to call `capture` from `ActionView::Helpers::CaptureHelper` module. It is automaticaly included into view context and you need to run it in this context so you need:

```
class Notification::Pseudo
  attr_accessor :message
  def initialize(vc, &block)
    @message = begin
      vc.capture(&block) if block_given?
    end || ""
  end
end

#In your view

- notification = Notification::Pseudo.new self do
  This is a test!
```

UPDATE:

To make it work also outside of the view, do:

```
class Notification::Pseudo
  attr_accessor :message
  def initialize(vc = nil, &block)
    @message = begin
      return unless block_given?
      vc ? vc.capture(&block) : block.call
    end || ""
  end
end
```

Comment: This would work if always initializing a Notification::Pseudo object from somewhere that had a view context but what about if I attempted to create on from the console? What is the proper way to do this without using a view context?

Comment: @KyleDecot Well, that depends on what you want it to do in that context. Let `vc = nil` by default, and then add logic to your constructor to make it behave differently if `vc == nil`.

Comment: Capture is to be used within a template - otherwise it has absolutely no sense to use it (It is internally calling Erb utils etc). You can fork it on existence of vc variable so this method is not called without view context.

Comment: That makes sense when you explain it like that. I didn't think about the view context being such an important part of the process. Thanks for breaking it down like that.